# How to specify the supported UTI types for action extension target

Tags: ios8, ios8-extension

> I implemented the action extension feature in my ios app. It was
>   working as i expected. But only one issue was there, in Xcode i do not
>   know how to configure the UTI types for action extension target. I
>   tried to adding some of the UTI types in the action extension info.plist but its not
>   reflecting. Actually i want to restrict my extension shows on host app based on some UTI types.

Any help that might be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported. The best you can do is configure the `NSExtensionActivationRule` entry in the extension's Info.plist. You can include values like `NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount` or `NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount` but you can't be as precise as you would with UTIs.

The full list of options appears in Apple's [Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/SystemExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW1). If the current system isn't precise enough for you, you should file an enhancement request with Apple.